# Using get_post_meta with new_to_publish

Tags: custom-field, post-status, post-meta

I'm trying to read the custom fields set by the user when publishing a new post:

```
function doSomething($post) {

   $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

   error_log("post meta: ".print_r($meta, true));

}

add_action("new_to_publish", "doSomething", 999);
add_action("draft_to_publish", "doSomething", 999);
add_action("pending_to_publish", "doSomething", 999);
```

The custom fields are there for draft_to_publish but not for new_to_publish.

If I use save_post it seems to work every time, but I need it to only run when the status is set to publish for the first time...

Comment: That's because the fields weren't set then. For e.g. Autosave doesn't save them, etc. Use the values from `$_POST` instead for your `"new_to_publish"` action.

Comment: Thanks @kaiser, didn't think to check $_POST. It worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the fields weren't set then. Note: The »Autosave« process/request also doesn't save them.

Use the values from `$_POST` instead for your `"new_to_publish"` action.

**EDIT:** Do **NOT** forget to escape and properly sanitize input data! Else you will open a security hole.

Comment: For all newbies who, like me, don't understand this answer - you should use `$value = $_POST['meta_key'];`

Comment: @GrafOrlov See update. Please escape your input data properly.